# Camel best practices for RESTfull web service exposing

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I want to expose a RESTfull webservice using camel. I have used URI templates to define my service contracts. I want to know how should I route the requests to the relevant method of my ServiceProcessor based on the URI template.

As an example, take the following two operations:

```
        @GET
        @Path("/customers/{customerId}/")
        public Customer loadCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") final String customerId){
            return null;
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/customers/{customerId}/accounts/")
        List<Account> loadAccountsForCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") final String customerId){
            return null;
        }
```

**Following is the route I have used:**

```
<osgi:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route trace="true" id="PaymentService">
        <from uri="`enter code here`cxfrs://bean://customerCareServer" />
        <process ref="customerCareProcessor" />
    </route>
</osgi:camelContext>
```

Is there any way that I can match the uri header(Exchange.HTTP_PATH) to an existing template uri in my service definition?

**Following is the Service Contract for my service:**

```
@Path("/customercare/")
public class CustomerCareService {

    @POST
    @Path("/customers/")
    public void registerCustomer(final Customer customer){

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/customers/{customerId}/accounts/")
    public void registerAccount(@PathParam("customerId") final String customerId, final Account account){

    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/customers/")
    public void updateCustomer(final Customer customer){

    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/accounts/")
    public void updateAccount(final Account account){

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/customers/{customerId}/")
    public Customer loadCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") final String customerId){
        return null;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/customers/{customerId}/accounts/")
    List<Account> loadAccountsForCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") final String customerId){
        return null;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/accounts/{accountNumber}")
    Account loadAccount(@PathParam("accountNumber") final String accountNumber){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cxfrs` endpoint consumer provides a special exchange header `operationName` that contains a service method name (`registerCustomer`, `registerAccount`, etc).

You could decide what to do with a request using this header like following:

```
<from uri="cxfrs://bean://customerCareServer" />
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${header.operationName} == 'registerCustomer'</simple>
        <!-- registerCustomer request processing -->
    </when>
    <when>
        <simple>${header.operationName} == 'registerAccount'</simple>
        <!-- registerAccount request processing -->
    </when>
    ....
</choice>
```